# why is group_by not showing in the pivot table i'm trying to make?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I'm trying to find the total earnings per supplier using the following code

```r
ealing_spend %>%
  group_by(`amended_supplier_name`) %>%
  summarise(total_earnings = sum(`net_amount`)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total_earnings))
```

but it keeps throwing up the total amount for the whole dataframe and not grouping by supplier. Any advice?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data (you can use `dput` and paste result or a tool from the `datapasta` package to make this easier)? It's easier to figure out what the problem is when we can replicate it.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you sure the value is not there? It should be the first column.

Comment: This is almost always due to a name conflict, you have likely loaded a package that defines a `summarize` function (like `plyr`) *after* loading `dplyr`, and you are using that package's `summarize` instead. If you specify `dplyr::summarize` that should work. See the linked dupe for more suggestions.